# Decrypted text from AES encryption has extra spaces

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I'm trying to decrypt passwords that were stored in a database from a standard SqlMembershipProvider.  In order to do this, I hacked together following console app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string encryptedPassword = @"wGZmgyql4prPIr7t1uaxa+RBRJC51qOPBO5ZkSskUtUCY1aBpqNifQGknEfWzky4";
        const string iv = @"Jc0RhfDog8SKvtF9aI+Zmw==";
        var password = Decrypt(encryptedPassword, iv);

        Console.WriteLine(password);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string Decrypt(string toDecrypt, string iv)
    {
        var ivBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(iv);
        const string decryptKey = "DECRYPTION_KEY_HERE";
        var keyArray = StringToByteArray(decryptKey);
        var toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(toDecrypt);
        var rDel = new AesCryptoServiceProvider() { Key = keyArray, IV = ivBytes};
        var cTransform = rDel.CreateDecryptor();
        var resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
    }

    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        var numberChars = hex.Length;
        var bytes = new byte[numberChars / 2];
        for (var i = 0; i < numberChars; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }
```

This does indeed decrypt the text, however instead of the resulting text being something like "Password1", it's "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0P\0a\0s\0s\0w\0o\0r\0d\01\0" which writes to the console as a bunch of spaces, then "P a s s w o r d 1".  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: decrypt a password? Huh? They should be stored as 1-way hashes, right?

Comment: I see an `iv`, but no [mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_of_operation) or [padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) -- perhaps the password was encrypted into the database using a different mode of encryption or padding than you're using to decrypt it? (Mode of operation doesn't seem _too_ likely, since you do get some meaningful data out, but still, go find what the encrypting routine does and reverse it exactly. :)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, these are from a legacy system that I inherited. I'm decrypting them precisely so I can restore them using a salted hash.

Comment: @sarnold It's the standard SqlMembershipProvider from a SharePoint site, with the PasswordFormat set to "Encrypted." I'm not exactly sure what they use for padding, but I've tried every single Padding setting on the AesCrytpoServiceProvider with no luck.

Comment: If this is not a homework or something like that, you should listen to Mitch: passwords are not encrypted using symmetric-key algorithms. You should only encrypt them using asymmetric crypto. and just compare the values.

Comment: @Giuliano0 As I replied above, I'm porting login information from a legacy system to a new one where the passwords will be stored in a salted hash. In order to do this, I need to be able to decrypt the existing passwords.

Comment: @Chris, excellent, I'm thrilled to hear that you're migrating to salted hashes! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that *part* of the problem might be that the original password was encoded as UTF-16 before encryption, and you're decoding it as UTF-8. Try changing the final line of your `Decrypt` method:

```
return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(resultArray);
```

That doesn't explain all those spurious leading zeros though. Very strange...

**EDIT...**

Actually, I seem to remember that `SqlMembershipProvider` prefixes the password bytes with a 16-byte salt before encryption, in which case you'll probably be able to get away with something like this:

```
return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(resultArray, 16, resultArray.Length - 16);
```

But that *still* doesn't explain why those 16 bytes are all zeros rather than a bunch of random values...

Comment: You're right! That removed the spaces within the password, but not the leading ones.

Comment: So in the database, there is a salt field, which was required as input for "iv" when I decrypt it.  You might be right that I can simply do what you suggested, I'm going to test it with passwords that begin with spaces, etc, to make sure.